# drawing scale floorplans in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

i want to draw scale floorplans in AI for interior room layouts, whats the best way to do this as i would like to draw them at 1:1 but for printing they need to be at 1:50 is there a way that i can use "viewports" (the way that vectorworks handles this problem) or is there another way that you could think of, other than selecting the drawing and using 
object > transfer > scale > 2% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrator has no CAD functions. Any scaling will have to be done manually either upon output or while creating.

There are plug ins which may or may not suit your needs for CAD functions. [Hot Door's CAD Tools](https://www.hotdoor.com/cadtools/overview) is one major plug-in vendor.

Comment: I'll second all this. Illustrator is great, but definitely not CAD software.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Illustrator for simple 2D room layouts (plans and elevations), and it works fine; I wouldn't use it if I had a dedicated CAD application to hand.

Create your drawing at a simple scale, probably 1:100, and worry about output scaling only when you need to print, so if you need 1:50, print at 200%.

Comment: when your drawing do you need to work out each line at 1:100 so if i was going to draw a 10 meter line would i just have to draw it in at 10cm in illustrator ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.